# Why do the $-1$-categories form a categeory rather than merely a set?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, higher-category-theory

The collection of $n$-categories naturally has the structure of a $(1+n)$-category. For example $\mathbf{Set}$ is a $1$-category and $\mathbf{Cat}$ is a $2$-category. Therefore we would expect the [$-1$-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28-1%29-category) to form a $0$-category, i.e. a set.

The $-1$-categories are precisely the empty category and the trivial category (these can be seen as the booleans or truth-values, false and true). But there's a functor from the empty category to the trivial category (false implies true). So the $-1$-categories actually form a $1$-category (admitedly a mere partial order) rather than a set as expected.

What's the explanation for this discrepancy in an otherwise straightforward pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because sets are the $0$-*groupoids*; they are the $0$-categories in which every morphism is invertible. In a set, if $\hom(x,y)$ is trivial, then $\hom(y,x)$ is trivial as well.

Its *posets* that are the $0$-*categories*.

It may be helpful to think of setoids rather than sets, and preorders instead of posets.

There's a [finer classification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(n,r)-category): an $(n,r)$-category is one where:

- $k$-morphisms are equivalences if $k>r$
- Parallel $k$-morphisms are equivalent for $k > n$

Sets are the $(0,0)$-categories, and posets are the $(0,1)$-categories. The usual definition of category is of $(1,1)$-categories.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clear things up! I added [my own answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2928986/1149) based on yours but explaining it in a way I found helpful.

Answer (score 2):

An $(n,r)$-category is an $\omega$-category such that:

- Any parallel $k$-morphisms are equivalent for $k>n$
- All $k$-morphisms are equivalences for $k>r$.

This allows us to draw a periodic table of $(n,r)$-categories:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
 r\downarrow \backslash n\rightarrow& -1 & 0 & 1& 2& \dots \\\hline
 0 &\text{boolean}&\text{set}&\text{groupoid}&\text{$2$-groupoid}&\\ \hline
 1  &\text{"}&\text{poset}&\text{category}&\color{grey}{\text{$(2,1)$-category}}&\\ \hline
 2  &\text{"}&\text{"}&\color{grey}{\text{$(1,2)$-category}}&\text{$2$-category}&\\ \hline
 3  &\text{"}&\text{"}&\color{grey}{\text{"}}&\color{grey}{\text{$(2,3)$-category}}&\\ \hline
 \vdots&  & & & &\ddots\\
\end{array}

(in which I have greyed out any cells not corresponding to a preexisting notion).

It's easy to see that the sequence $(\text{boolean}, \text{ set}, \text{ category}, \text{ $2$-category},\dots)$, which I thought was the definition of an $n$-category, actually forms a crooked line in this table.

There are two ways to straighten it:

- If we wanted to continue the sequence $(\text{boolean}, \text{ set}, \dots)$ in a straight line, we should continue it with $(\dots,\text{ groupoid}, \text{ $2$-groupoid}, \dots)$.
- If instead we wanted the element before the beginning of the sequence $(\text{set}, \text{ category}, \text{ $2$-category},\dots)$, we should take precisely the $(-1,-1)$-categories. These are off the top of the table, but I believe they include only the empty category (the object of the trivial category cannot be an equivalence, because there is no $0$-morphism "going the other way" to compose it with). The empty category on its own does indeed form a set.

In every case, we have that $\mathbf{(n,r)}$-$\mathbf{Cat}$ is a $(1+n,1+r)$-category (at least in the nontrivial part of the table where $1+n\geq r$). So there are no strange anomalies.

Comment: The usual convention would have a $(-1,-1)$-category also a Boolean: nothing new happens when you take negative $r$. This is described on the nLab page for $(n,r)$-categories, although I admit the argument is a bit fuzzy on why every $0$-morphism should be viewed as an equivalence. In any case, it's on much firmer ground to go one more step left, where a $(-2)$-groupoid is a point.

Comment: Incidentally, your grayed boxes can be viewed as known objects via enrichment, more or less: an $(n,r)$-category is a category enriched in $(n-1,r-1)$-categories, up to details about how weak the enrichment is, which also come up in for instance the question of whether a $(2,2)$-category is a $2$-category or a bicategory. But at the very least, enriching strictly gives many important examples.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Perhaps we should say that the category of $-1$-categories is the *set* of booleans; getting rid of the morphism $0\to 1$? That would have the nice consequence that a set is precisely a category enriched in $-1$-categories, because we could no longer have $x\geq y$ but not $y\geq x$. Likewise the category of $(0,-1)$-categories might be the *groupoid* of sets and bijections, and so on.

Comment: We could see groupoids as categories enriched in sets-and-bijections by treating the category of sets-and-bijections as a *multicategory* whose morphisms $(A_1,\dots,A_k)\to B$ are the functions $A_1\times \dots\times A_k\to B$ that are bijective in each argument.